# Facebook like and share create a fanpage

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

We are using the facebook like plugin with the share button. The URL points to a resource of our app. For example

```
http://apps.facebook.com/appname/resources/id
```

The first time this resource/url is shared or liked, everything works fine. The share for example holds the URL given above.

But if the same resource/url is shared again, an error occurs. Facebook did create a fanpage for that resource like

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/appname
```

So from now on, share/likes refer to that page instead of the resource/url of our app.

The URL we use for the like plugin is correct and always points to the app resource URL. The fbappid in there is correct, too. Furthermore the page of the resource holds open graph meta tags like og:url, also pointing to the correct URL.

The facebook linter/debugger returns URLs to the correct app resource URLs, when checking the liked/shared resource.

Why is a fanpage created instead and the URL exchanged in shares/likes? How to fix it? We want the share to include the URL of the app resource and to increase the like count for that open graph object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a related facebook bug for this:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240986412684045?browse=search_4fe13eff357e29b43787690

So, apparently there is nothing we could do about it, but wait for facebook to fix it. The alternative would be what CBroe suggested and point to the ressource without using the canvas URL. But this would put the non-canvas URL in the shared message, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 1):

> We want the share to include the URL of the app resource and to increase the like count for that open graph object.

If you just want to increase like count fo your OG object, why don’t you link your actual URL, and not a Facebook URL? I mean, your app should be accessible via yourdomain.example.com/something/resources/id, right? So why not like *that*, since it is the *real* Open Graph object …?

Comment: Thanks +CBroe. We don't want to do it like that, because we want users who receive the share to be directed to the URL of our facebook app if they click the contained link.